# SASS background issue in iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, css, ipad, sass

I have an issue using the **background** property in the sass

When I write:

```
background: url(../images/assets/calendar.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 250px 230px;
background-position: 51px 91px;
background-color: $mainColor;
```

The sass compile it for:

```
background: url(../images/assets/calendar.png) 51px 91px/250px 230px no-repeat #f68e34;
```

But, the iPhone and iPad browsers don't understand this syntax, how can I resolve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The provided Sass does not compile to that CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `background-image` instead of the `background` shorthand?

If you write out each rule iOS/Safari will understand it.

```
background-image: url(../images/assets/calendar.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 250px 230px;
background-position: 51px 91px;
background-color: $mainColor;
```

Comment: How I have not thought about it? lol - Thank you so much!